# More than one static path in local Flask instance

Tags: python, html, flask

Is that possible to add more static paths for my local dev Flask instance?
I want to have default `static` folder for storing js/css/images files for the site and another folder, e.g. `designs` to keep my specific assets. I don't want to place `designs` folder inside `static` if there is a better solution exists.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I have been using following approach:

```
# Custom static data
@app.route('/cdn/<path:filename>')
def custom_static(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH'], filename)
```

The `CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH` variable is defined in my configuration.

And in templates:

```
{{ url_for('custom_static', filename='foo') }}
```

*Caveat emptor* - I'm not really sure whether it's secure ;)

Comment: In my eyes this is the most custom version but you should use `werkzeug.utils.secure_filename` to check the filename.

Comment: clarification for anyone to come 'CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH' is I believe the actual folder name path. it's not some special key/variable.... which for some reason I thought it was.

Comment: actually, @Eiyrioü,  I took it the other way, and also got it to work.  I used the code as-is, and added a `CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH` variable in my config file.

Comment: what is `cdn` here? also should the `<path:filename>` be used as it is or should I replace `filename` with the actual file name?

Comment: @Jarus: `flask.send_from_directory` already checks that the filename don't point outside the directory. `werkzeug.utils.secure_filename` is for safely naming new files, and is not relevant here. I actually think it instead can break things by for example removing dirs, spaces and umlauts.

Answer (score 52):

You can use a Blueprint with its own static dir
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/

Blueprint

```
blueprint = Blueprint('site', __name__, static_url_path='/static/site', static_folder='path/to/files')
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

Template

```
{{ url_for('site.static', filename='filename') }}
```

Comment: This feels like the cleanest solution to me. It utilizes the existing mechanisms for serving static files and doesn't require adding routes for them.

Answer (score 4):

If i have images stored in images dir like following

```
images/
  dir1/
    image1.jpg
  dir2/
    image2.jpg
```

then we can access these images with following url:
http://localhost:5000/images/dir1/image1.jpg
with the help of below code

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='main_static_dir')


@app.route('/images/<path:filename>')
def base_static(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.root_path + '/images/', filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to expand on the accepted answer above for anyone who was wondering what `app.config['CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH']` was being set to.

In my case I needed a `/.well-known` dir and so here's what I used:

I placed a new dir in my app root called `well-known`.
I set a config var like so:

```
CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH=app.root_path + '/well-known/'
```

I then used that var as such:

```
@app.route('/.well-known/<path:filename>')
def wellKnownRoute(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH'], filename, conditional=True)
```

Setting `conditional=True` is smart, this will 404 any requests where the file does not exist.

And of course if you're wondering why you need to set a config value for the dir path, you don't. You can always just use the config's value in place, giving you this instead:

```
@app.route('/.well-known/<path:filename>')
def wellKnownRoute(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.root_path + '/well-known/', filename, conditional=True)
```

My files for the `/.well-known` URL path were always going to come from the app root `/well-known` dir so no point in making it more complicated.

And to note, you would be better off handling this particular case from nginx or whatever server you're using by setting up an additional server block and serving the file from outside the app, I just needed this setup for a dev env for testing.