# Custom Folders in Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, flask

So I want to include some js and css files in my html page that flask serves but want them in /js/ and /cs/ instead of all in /static/ grouped together.

I tried to do this [More than one static path in local Flask instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513072/more-than-one-static-path-in-local-flask-instance)

using:

(part of the randomly named cat.html)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('css_static',filename='bootstrap.min.css')}}">        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettify.css">
```

and

(part of app.py)

```
@app.route('/sigma')
def sig():
        return render_template('cat.html')

@app.route('/css/<path:fn>')
def css_static(fn):
        return send_from_directory('/css/',fn)

@app.route('/js/<path:fn>')
def js_static(fn):
        return send_from_directory(app.config['JS_STATIC'],fn)
```

---

when I try this it doesn't work (the `/cat.html`) shows Internal Server Error.

and when I go to `/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css` it loads forever....

so what am I doing wrong?

Edit: it seems the only directory open is `/static/...` which I don't know why since I have a `/js/` route.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to define a route for that. Just place your "js" and "css" directories inside the static dir.

Here's what i do :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ config["APP_URL"] }}/static/css/style.css">
```

replace the app url part with your domain.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def Home_page():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/images/<filename>')
def images_folder(filename):  
    return send_from_directory('images', filename)

@app.route('/css/<filename>')
def css_folder(filename):  
    return send_from_directory('css', filename)

@app.route('/js/<filename>')
def js_folder(filename):  
    return send_from_directory('js', filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you want to download all files: [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZRaMJO7xvcf51v5m5Ay7B9rSuOZ3uYbg/view?usp=sharing)