# How can I serve NPM packages using Flask?

Tags: python, node.js, flask, npm, pip

I have a [small Flask app](https://github.com/danvk/webdiff) which currently sources jQuery and highlight.js from external servers. I'd like to make these local dependencies which I pull in via NPM.

What is the standard practice for this? Should I create `package.json` file in the same directory as my `static` and `templates` directories and serve `node_modules` as a separate static dir ala this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513072/more-than-one-static-path-in-local-flask-instance)?

I'm packaging and distributing my app using `pip`, so any solution needs to be compatible with that.

Comment: Have you seen [fantastic](http://www.fanstatic.org/en/latest/intro.html)?  It's not the last word in package management for JS (like webjars I don't think it's 100% there yet), but it might make things easier.

Comment: @SeanVieira , good advice! The package flask_fanstatic (https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Fanstatic/) makes it even easier. Also, there's no need for many package managers, pip alone can do it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Go to your static folder and there initialize your npm project.

```
cd flask_app/static
$ npm init
```

after installing and saving npm packages you can serve them like this:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/toastr/toastr.js')}}"></script>
```

credits to: https://codeburst.io/creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-python-npm-webpack-and-react-8925800503d9

Comment: Is there any different in doing the <script> like you did, versus doing `<script src="node_modules/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>`?

Comment: @BruceWayne using url_for allows yo to separate your real project structure from the actual static endpoint being served by Flask. You can get more info in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234593/setting-up-static-folder-path-in-flask
See that Flask docs also recommend to do this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/jquery/#loading-jquery

Comment: as long as front end libraries and technologies keep changing with the wind... this will for sure be the best answer since now **Bower** is deprecated...

Comment: Isn't webpack made to support this?

Answer (score 0):

You need [Bower](http://bower.io/) and you already have NPM. This is all you need to achieve what you want.

Basically, you will have to create a `package.json` in the root to install Bower using NPM. Then you will have to create a `bower.json` to define what all libraries you need, example jQuery.

Then your flow will be like:

```
npm install
bower install
```

This will basically install bower for you and the other frontend libraries you defined in `bower.json`.

All bower components will go into a directory called `bower_components` in your root. This is where all your installed bower packages will reside. You can use these packages inside your templates now.

Also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079833/how-to-change-bowers-default-components-folder) to make sure that bower's packages are installed in your `static` or `assets` folder which you want to serve.

Comment: The answer to my question was basically "Have you heard of Bower". :)

Comment: This is not a good answer to the question. Some packages, like angular2, will not support bower and only NPM, so an answer is still needed on how to get Flask serving up node_modules during development

Comment: This answer might have been correct in 2014, but in 2018 you really shouldn't be using Bower anymore, the project is deprecated and will probably stop functioning somewhere in the future. Go with a `package.json` and `npm`, as indicated in @a2k's answer.

Comment: Bower is no longer a thing so I've changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit late for the answer, but the easiest way to do it is by doing this:

```
sudo npm install bower
echo "bower_components/" >> .gitignore
bower install -S (here goes whatever you want)
npm init
```

Then you fill out the prompt, and you'll have a few new files:

- `bower.json`, which is generated by bower to manage dependencies.
  Using `bower install -S (your dependency)` will update this file with
  your new dependencies.
- `package.json`, created by npm to manage your project and npm
  dependencies
- `node_modules`, the things you installed with npm
- `bower_components/` which is where all of your front end dependencies
  live.