# Setting up static folder path in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Seems like my static files aren't being served properly. This is what it looks like right now:

```
myApp
    __init__.py
    static
       img
       js
         bootstrap.min.js
       etc.
```

This is what my app config in my `__init__.py` looks like:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static")
```

This is the error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2014 13:12:01] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

As far as the url routing goes, no problems there, localhost/home routes to home, localhost/contact routes to contact, etc. But static files aren't being found :( Am I missing something?

NOTE: I'm hosting this on my Mac, purely local host

This is my `__init__.py` main method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Running as:

```
python __init.py__
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you are hardcoding to static file URLs. You tell Flask to server them with no URL prefix -- the default would have been `/static` -- but the log shows the request going to `/static/js/bootstrap.min.js`. You probably have something like the following in a template file.

```
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Instead, you should use `url_for` to create the URL for you. Change the above to

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

This will result in

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, this is it! One quick question though, would the "url_for("static"" relate to the "static_folder" path set in my app?

Comment: When a static asset is requested, Flask's `static` endpoint will try to serve it from the folder specified for `static_folder`.

Comment: can i change the static folder i am working with npm to install npm package to the frontend so i  need to change to node_modules

Comment: @juancarlospeñacabrera yes, that is what `static_folder` is for.