# Webpack for serving JS per Flask Application

Tags: python, node.js, flask, npm, webpack

I have a Flask application I have built locally and have hit the wall as to having javascript with npm packages being able to be used because I am consuming REST APIs and using jQuery per my application. I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514936/how-can-i-serve-npm-packages-using-flask) and have Webpack working.

I ran the command `npm run watch`

```
    webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch

  0% compiling
Webpack is watching the files…

Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.21
Time: 4836ms

    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names

bundle.js  5.97 MB       0  [emitted]  main
[366] ./js/index.js 15.3 kB {0} [built]
   + 366 hidden modules
```

So now I have webpack working with my index.js file and I have the Flask app being served using gunicorn and Docker on 5000.

Everything is working, but my JS is still unresponsive in my Flask application.

Does anyone know what I do to have my index.js file to work per this Flask app with these components I have, or what I am doing incorrectly here?

Here is my html template, rendering just fine. Just not any Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description"
          content="{% block meta_description %}{% endblock %}">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/main.css') }}">

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}">

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/watson.css') }}">

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/vendor/font-awesome.min.css') }}">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="{{ url_for('page.home') }}">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="container">
      <div class="md-margin-top">{% block heading %}{% endblock %}</div>
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </main>

    <footer class="footer text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li class="text-muted">2018</li>
          <li><a href="{{ url_for('page.privacy') }}">NMT</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url_for('page.terms') }}">How it works</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <script
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/vendor/bootstrap.min.js') }}">    
    </script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bundle.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/v2.js') }}"></script>


   <script  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/index.js') }}"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

The parts involved in the question: https://jsfiddle.net/cgnws2u3/3/

Error Logs

I updated filepath and now get this per my js files I am trying to link to my project:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at v2-generated.ts:17
```

Comment: Could you provide Flask app and browser logs?

Comment: Hey @Alex, yes I added them.

Comment: Does it happen only to JS files? Could you see the same error (404) while requesting CSS files?

Comment: Could you provide the `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your Flask project structure contains `static` folder as per [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/).

According to the relative `bundle.js` file path in `index.html` template, your `static` directory should contain `js` directory. Make sure you have it there after using `webpack` and it contains your `bundle.js`, `index.js` and the rest of files mentioned in your template.

Comment: Yes it does. Maybe since this is not working, might need to try out Browserify instead.