# Custom static path in flask api?

Tags: python, templates, flask

I have referred the link here: [More than one static path in local Flask instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513072/more-than-one-static-path-in-local-flask-instance) and tried getting to display the image files in the browser tab, but couldn't do so. Unable to make out the mistake.
stored_name is the physical filename of the file stored in the path specified by the app config constant variable: 'UPLOAD_FOLDER'. **This folder is NOT in the static folder and its sub-folder path**. I would like to increase storage capacity of files (maybe image files also), later by adding harddisk space, which is difficult if I use the static folder for storage. I don't want to override the static folder during app initialisation(which works)

Code snippets:

from flask import send_from_directory

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/docs/<path:filename>', methods=["GET"])
def img_render(filename):
    print 'Called here'
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)


@app.route('/api/v1.0/docs/<int:doc_id>',methods=["GET"])
def image_rendering(doc_id):
    s = select([docs]).where(docs.c.id==doc_id)
    rs = conn.execute(s).fetchone()
    filename = str(rs[docs.c.stored_name])

    return url_for('img_render', filename=filename)
```

Html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="{{url_for('img_render', filename=filename) }}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The template is in the templates folder itself.  If I override the original static folder during init of the application, I am able to get the images displayed in the browser, but I have to change my reference to the static folder for the application **OR** I will have to upload images into the static folder from the application, which **I don't want to do.**   What is the mistake that it just displays **the path of the image in the browser** example:

> /api/v1.0/docs/1_20160707_121214.jpg

and not the image itself? Where is the mistake in the code? Using flask v .0.11, linux 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `image_rendering` method is returning a string (which is what you see in the browser) when it should be returning the result of a template rendering.

Replace 'mytemplate.html' with the name of your html template in the following sample.

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/api/v1.0/docs/<int:doc_id>',methods=["GET"])
def image_rendering(doc_id):
    s = select([docs]).where(docs.c.id==doc_id)
    rs = conn.execute(s).fetchone()
    filename = str(rs[docs.c.stored_name])

    return render_template('mytemplate.html', filename=filename)
```

Here is a simple Flask App that works in Windows. In my d:\temp folder there is a file `test.jpg`. Make sure your Flask App has the correct permissions to read the files in the upload folder. To use browse to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/docs/99`:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'd:/temp'


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/api/v1.0/docs/<path:filename>', methods=["GET"])
def img_render(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename=filename, mimetype='image/jpeg')


@app.route('/api/v1.0/docs/<int:doc_id>',methods=["GET"])
def image_rendering(doc_id):
    #  ignore doc_id, we'll use a constant filename
    filename = 'test.jpg'
    return render_template('test.html', filename=filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

test.html in the `templates` folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="{{url_for('img_render', filename=filename) }}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried the above also. It just displays a thumbnail, but not the actual image.

Comment: In your `img_render` function instead of printing 'Called here' print the filename passed into the function i.e. `print filename` . Is this the expected name of the image ?

Comment: In the `img_render` function also print out the upload folder path i.e. `print app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` - is that correct ?

Comment: Yes,app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] is correct; but in console what I get is "GET /1_20160707_174342.jpg HTTP/1.1, 404

Comment: What is the actual value of `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`

Comment: The physical full path where the actual image file resides; as mentioned this is not part of the static folder path. app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] value is : '/opt/abc/images'

Comment: I think I can see what's happening - get back to your shortly.

Comment: Thx a lot. Actually the path was created dynamically, hence there was problem in rendering the image. Works great now.