# Weird issue with download trigger

Tags: javascript, html, flask, download

I have a flask app in which I have a front end html with multiple features.

This front end html template has a "download button" to download a file.

This is how I am triggering a download:

```
$('#download_excel').attr('onClick',"window.open('/static/excel.xlsx')");
```

download_excel corresponds to a bottom to download a file. This works fine.

But, if I move my excel.xlsx file to a different folder say "download" and modify the above line to this:

```
$('#download_excel').attr('onClick',"window.open('/download/excel.xlsx')");
```

This show no file here: (`http://127.1.1.1:5555/download/excel.xlsx)`

Why? what is the difference?

Comment: do not bind events with `attr`

Comment: Is the download folder public and accessible? Seems like you have to make your server allow that path.

Comment: The difference is the URL. Is there some sort of handler or directory or...? for resources in that location?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Flask only serves files from the static folder. You have to specify another static folder path as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519004/5868802

Answer (score 0):

This is because Flask has a default endpoint for static files (files accessible publicly) at `/static`. This endpoints binds to directory `static` in your project folder.

You can rebind this endpoint in Flask constructor:

```py
Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/download", static_folder='download')
```